# Get Value from Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to get the string value from the node passcode in my Firebase database to compare with a user input, but unfortunately I am not able to get the value. This is the link to my firebase database in the below image.

[image: Firebase Database screenshot]

This is my codes below:

```
 final DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("pin_code");

        mDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String rface = (String) dataSnapshot.child("pincode").getValue();
                if (rface.equals(userPassword) && !rface.equals("")){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(PinActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                else {
                    if (rface.equals("") || rface.equals(null)){
                        // Creating new user node, which returns the unique key value
                        // new user node would be /users/$userid/
                        String userId = mDatabase.push().getKey();

                        // creating user object
                        Pin pin = new Pin(authUserId, userPassword);

                        mDatabase.child(userId).setValue(pin);

                        Intent intent = new Intent(PinActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(PinActivity.this,"Invalid PIN code", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return;
                    }

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
```

**This is the json code**

```
  {
  "pin_code" : {
"id" : "TQYTo1NHNnhPJnOxhe1Vok3U6ic2",
"pincode" : "12345"
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("pin_code")` does not refer to the node you're looking for. Most likely you *know* the `id` property, in which case you can get the node with:

```
DatabaseReference collection = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("p...");
Query query = collection.orderByChild("id").equalTo("TQT...ic2");

query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
      for (DataSnapshot child: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        String rface = (String) child.child("pincode").getValue();
        if (rface.equals(userPassword) && !rface.equals("")){
```

The changes I made:

1. On the first line we get the collection: the node under which you want to run a query. You struck out the name of that node in the screenshot, but it's the second line you marked.
2. In the second line we create a query on the `id` property of each child node under the collection.
3. In the `onDataChange` we added a loop. This is needed because a query against the Firebase Database will potentially have multiple results. So the `dataSnapshot` contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result. We loop over `dataSnapshot.getChildren()` to handle those multiple results.

If there can ever only be one node with the same `id`, you should consider changing your data structure to use the `id` as the key of the node. So:

```
pin_codes
  uid1: "pincode1"
  uid2: "pincode2"
```

Your code then becomes significantly simpler, because you don't need to query for the user anymore. You can just directly read from the path:

```
DatabaseReference user = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("pin_codes").child("TQT...ic2");

user.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String rface = (String) dataSnapshot.getValue();
        if (rface.equals(userPassword) && !rface.equals("")){
```

Comment: i edited my codes with your suggestion but now it returns nothing for me.

Comment: I had a mistake in my initial snippet. I just fixed that, so have a look if that fixes the problem you have now.

Comment: i used the second approach and its not returning any value

Comment: this is codes.  DatabaseReference user = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("pin_code").child("TQYTo1NHNnhPJnOxhe1Vok3U6ic2");

            user.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    String rface = (String) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                    if (rface.equals(userPassword) && !rface.equals("")){
                        //do something
                    }
                }

Comment: i get this error java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference

Comment: Please don't add blocks of code in comments. As you may notice it becomes unreadable. Instead edit your question (there's a link right under it) and add the up-to-date code and corresponding JSON structure. For the latter, please add it as text and not a screenshot. You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: thanks for the heads up. i have updated my codes with the json i exported.

Comment: The first code snippet works with your current data structure. The second code snippet requires that you change your data structure to match the JSON I put in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try change this:

```
String rface = (String) dataSnapshot.child("pincode").getValue();
```

To this:

```
String rface = (String) dataSnapshot.child("pincode").getValue(String.class);
```

Comment: when i added that i had this error java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference on this line if (rface.equals(userPassword) && !rface.equals(""))

Answer (score 0):

Use the following::

```
Object some = dataSnapshot.getValue();
String value = some.toString();
```